# Can Apache Derby embedded db file be split into multiple file?

Tags: file, derby, segments

I am writing a java app with an embedded Derby DB. Because the storage is going to be massive, the db file as well grows huge.

I wonder if the db could be switched to new file or segment once a certain limit is reached.

Is this achievable with Apache Derby?

Comment: What is the "certain limit" that you are concerned about?

Comment: The database is stored in multiple files, but there is just one file per table or index - see https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/cdevdvlp40724.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton by certain limit, I mean after the file has reached some size, I want to switch to another file

Comment: Well, since each table is indeed its own file, you could rename your existing table and create a new table with the same columns. Then your existing data would remain in the existing file, and the new table would create a new file.